# snmptrap command examples in linux with rfc2578 mib

Tags: linux, snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap

Could you guys please give me examples for snmptrap command for linux with IpAddress, TimeTicks, Counter32 , Counter64.
I know I have to download rfc2578 mib, could you guys tell me what should i give the file name as because when I execute the command

```
sudo snmptrap -v 2c -c public 172.23.111.246 "" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6141.2.60.37.0.2 1.3.6.1.4.1.6141.2.60.37.1.1.11.1.1.1 TimeTicks
```

I get error :

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.6141.2.60.37.1.1.11.1.1.1: Missing type/value for variable
```

if i execute :

```
sudo snmptrap -v 2c -c public 172.23.111.246 "" 1.3.6.1.4.1.6141.2.60.37.0.2 1.3.6.1.4.1.6141.2.60.37.1.1.11.1.1.1 t TimeTicks
```

error is :

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.6141.2.60.37.1.1.11.1.1.1: Bad value notation (TimeTicks)
```

Comment: Do you have a MIB detailing what kind of object `1.3.6.1.4.1.6141.2.60.37.1.1.11.1.1.1` is?
The general format of [arguments to snmptrap](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmptrap.html) is `snmptrap -v [2c|3] [COMMON OPTIONS] [-Ci] uptime trap-oid [OID TYPE VALUE]`.
This would suggest that besides OID (1.3.6.1.4.1.6141.2.60.37.1.1.11.1.1.1) you also need to specify a type and a value.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see a programming question here.
That said, you don't actually need the MIB file in order to send stuff from snmptrap command line. You just use the MIB to look up what the data type is for a variable. Please read the man page for "snmpcmd" to find out what arguments are needed to send a TimeTicks value.